# $\text{rank}(Z)=p$ for almost all $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

First, we need to specify a measure on the matrix space of $n\times p$-matrices: Identifying $\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{np}$ by stacking the columns, we equip this space with Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb{R}^{np}$, i.e. $dZ=\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^p dZ_{ij}$. The task at hand is to prove that $\text{rank}(Z)=p$ for almost all $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$. I don't even know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove that the set $N$ of matrices whose rank is $\leqslant p-1$ has measure $0$. Define for a subset $I$ of $ \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $p$ elements and 
$$N_I:=\{A\in \mathbb R^{n\times p},\Delta_I(A)=0\},$$
where $\Delta_I(A)$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$ whose rows indexed by $\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus I$ has been removed. Since a matrix with $n$ row and $p$ columns (with $p\leqslant n$) has rank $p$ if and only if the determinant of an extracted matrix of size $p\times p$ is not zero, we have 
$$N=\bigcup_{\substack{I \subset \{1,\dots,n\}\\\operatorname{card}I=p}}N_I,$$
hence it suffices to show that the Lebesgue measure of $N_I$ is zero for each subset $I$ of $ \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $p$ elements. 
To this aim, we use the fact that the determinant of a matrix of size $p\times p$ is a polynomial function and the set of its zeros [has a null measure](http://www1.uwindsor.ca/math/sites/uwindsor.ca.math/files/05-03.pdf).